# Semaphore scenario code

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

Here in this scenario i am trying to replica a real ATM machine use case, i. e at a E-Bank kiosk we have four ATM's at a time, so 4 people(Threads) can make transaction at a time.

For this i am using **Semaphore** to achieve the threads limit restrictions, but i am getting non predictable output.

```
 package multithreadinglearning;

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
 import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
 import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

 public class ATMSemaphoreExample implements Runnable {

Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(4);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int balance = 1000;

Accounts a;
Accounts b;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        exec.submit(new ATMSemaphoreExample());
}

@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + ":" + Thread.currentThread() + " : acquiring lock...");
    System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + ":" + Thread.currentThread() + " : available Semaphore permits now: "
            + sem.availablePermits());

    try {
        sem.acquire();

        System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + ":" + Thread.currentThread() + " : got the permit...");
        System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + ":" + Thread.currentThread()
                + " : in available Semaphore permits now: " + sem.availablePermits());

        System.out.println("enter sender");
        String sender = sc.next();
        System.out.println("enter reciever");

        String reciver = sc.next();

        a = Bank.getAccount(sender);
        b = Bank.getAccount(reciver);

        System.out.println("a" + a);
        System.out.println("b" + b);

        System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + ":" + "i am " + Thread.currentThread() + "transafering money");

        System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + ":" + Thread.currentThread()
                + " :  inside available Semaphore permits now: " + sem.availablePermits());

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Accounts.transfer(a, b, 1000);

        System.out.println("balance A:" + a.balance);
        System.out.println("balance B:" + b.balance);

        System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + ":" + Thread.currentThread() + " : releasing lock...");
        sem.release();
        System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + ":" + Thread.currentThread() + " : available Semaphore permits now: "
                + sem.availablePermits());
    } catch (InterruptedException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the output i am getting:

```
   11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main] : acquiring lock...
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main] : acquiring lock...
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main] : acquiring lock...
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main] : acquiring lock...
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-9,5,main] : acquiring lock...
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main] : available Semaphore permits 
 now: 4
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-7,5,main] : acquiring lock...
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-6,5,main] : acquiring lock...
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-10,5,main] : acquiring lock...
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-5,5,main] : acquiring lock...
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-10,5,main] : available Semaphore permits 
 now: 4
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-5,5,main] : available Semaphore permits 
 now: 4
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-8,5,main] : acquiring lock...
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-5,5,main] : got the permit...
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-10,5,main] : got the permit...
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-6,5,main] : available Semaphore permits 
 now: 4
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-7,5,main] : available Semaphore permits 
 now: 4
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main] : got the permit...
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-9,5,main] : available Semaphore permits 
now: 4
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main] : available Semaphore permits 
 now: 4
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main] : available Semaphore permits 
 now: 4
11:46:39.888:Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main] : available Semaphore permits 
 now: 4
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main] : got the permit...
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main] : got the permit...
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-9,5,main] : got the permit...
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main] : in available Semaphore permits 
 now: 3
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-7,5,main] : got the permit...
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-6,5,main] : got the permit...
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-7,5,main] : in available Semaphore permits 
 now: 3
enter sender
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-10,5,main] : in available Semaphore 
 permits now: 3
enter sender
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-5,5,main] : in available Semaphore permits 
now: 3
enter sender
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-8,5,main] : available Semaphore permits 
 now: 4
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-6,5,main] : in available Semaphore permits 
 now: 3
enter sender
enter sender
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-9,5,main] : in available Semaphore permits 
 now: 3
enter sender
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main] : in available Semaphore permits 
 now: 3
enter sender
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main] : in available Semaphore permits 
now: 3
enter sender
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main] : got the permit...
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-8,5,main] : got the permit...
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main] : in available Semaphore permits 
 now: 3
enter sender
11:46:39.889:Thread[pool-1-thread-8,5,main] : in available Semaphore permits 
now: 3
enter sender
```

Here in the output why all the Threads are getting entered into the business code of run() method and asking for user input instead of **only 4**.

Answer (score 1):

Every runnable instance (ATMSemaphoreExample) has its own Semaphore.

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(4);
```

they don't have any effect to another thread.

Declare sem as static type to let all thread using the same instance of semaphore.

```
private static Semaphore sem =  new Semaphore(4);
```

or pass semaphore from main.

Comment: ok thanks:) and one more question here, as when i entering the sender account name and reciever account name , and the code is performing transfer() , why every thread is creating its own balance instance, why not taking the last updated balance.

Comment: it is the same as sem issue, but not only modify it to static. you also need to care about race condition and visible issue.
     private static volatile int balance;
     private syncoroniced void changeBalance(){
         ...
    }

Comment: yes i have made it private static final and it works consistently and maintaing integrity of balance.